# Installing Xamarin in VS2012 or VS2013 what are the pro & cons?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin, visual-studio-2013, compare, installation

This is very common question but this is not about the VS2012 & VS2013 features comparison. Instead this question is written to see the clear view of the technical parts of programming & effectiveness of Xamarin in VS2012 / VS2013.

Hope anyone could contribute to share their answers.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin is not supported in Visual Studio 2012.  You either need VS2013 Pro or better, or any edition of VS2015 or VS2017.

[Xamarin Visual Studio Requirements](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/#Windows_Requirements)